# Maximize Azure Cosmos DB Writes

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have an application that generates a lot of data times (10,000+ items), each item is about 44 KB. I am trying to find the fastest way to save the items to Cosmos DB. I have used two different ways to bulk add items to the DB, but they have about the same performance and it has been deemed too slow.

Way One:

```
    CosmosClient cosmos = new CosmosClient(uri, secret,
                    new CosmosClientOptions
                    {
                        RequestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120),
                        AllowBulkExecution = true,
                        ConnectionMode = Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ConnectionMode.Direct,                    
                    });

    Container itemContainer = database.GetContainer(containerName);

    List<Task> toWaitOn = new List<Task>();
    items.ForEach(x => toWaitOn.Add(LineMembers.CreateItemAsync(x, pk)));
    await Task.WhenAll(toWaitOn);
```

Way Two:

```
ConnectionPolicy ConnectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
            {
                ConnectionMode = Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionMode.Direct,
                ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
                RequestTimeout = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0),
                MaxConnectionLimit = 1000,
                RetryOptions = new RetryOptions
                {
                    MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 10,
                    MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 60
                }
            };

using(var client = new DocumentClient(
                    new Uri(Uri), secret,
                    ConnectionPolicy))
            {
                var tasks = new List<Task>();
                DocumentCollection dataCollection = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(dbName))
                .Where(c => c.Id == containerName).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
    
                for(int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
                {
                    tasks.Add(InsertDocument(1, client, dataCollection, items.Cast<object>().ToList()));
                }
            }
```

Does anyone know of another way to bulk add data to Cosmos DB, or if there is a way to scale out the writes?

UPDATE:
Too slow was deemed by it taking longer than a minute and a half to run. However, on closer inspection we found that the json that was being produced contained a lot of duplicate data. Once we refactored the data we got the saving under 30 seconds.

Thank you,
Travis Pettry

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-overview

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I thought was replaced in V3 of the API

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson thanks but I found that to be twice as slow as my other two methods

Comment: Really? It's only a year old and it has been replaced already? I can't keep up

Comment: Not sure how you define "too slow" - can you please edit your question to elaborate? Slowdowns are typically due to throttling when RU are exhausted. Are you seeing evidence of throttling (429)?

Comment: Bulk executor library is the best way AFAIK to bulk add documents to Cosmos DB as it is an out of box capability supported by the SDK and performant. As David said, 429 can prove that your requests are throttled. Pls add more details around this.